# Facebook Application - Like Button

Tags: facebook, flash, actionscript-3, fbml

I'd like to develop a Flash/Flex based application that I'll integrate withing my Page on Facebook.

I've seen on many applications that in order for a user too see more stuff on the application, user first of all has to click LIKE button on my page.

I've searched but couldn't find right thing I've been looking for, probably I don't know how to search for it correctly.

Maybe you could help me out to find right source for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Liking the app really matter.

What you might be looking for is *authorization* from the facebook users. For instance if your app need to post status update on the user's wall, you'll need to get authorisation from him/her first.

You should probably read this (rather generic) intro on facebook's developer website:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

This might be a helpful read too:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/116/

Finally, haven't done it in AS3 but apparently Adobe has an as3 version of the facebook sdk available:

http://www.adobe.com/newsletters/inspire/november2010/articles/article6/index.html

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

Comment: I don't think you are correct. It's called fangating, and it's a common practice.

Answer (score 1):

what you are reffering to is liking a page beofore being able to interact with an application that has been embedded into a page.  A page tab app.
You need to parse the `signed_request` that facebook passes to your application and once you have parsed it you will be able to see if the user has liked your page or not.
[Here is a link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) to some more information about `singed_requests`